# Generate a file from a string without having to create a template file in Chef?

Tags: chef-infra

I currently use this code in a recipe:

```rb
template "/var/django/.ssh/id_rsa" do
    source "id_rsa.erb"
    owner "django"
    group "django"
    variables :key => ssh_key
    mode 00600
end
```

And here's what `id_rsa.erb` looks like:

```rb
<%= @key %>
```

I was wondering if I could avoid having a template, and simply produce the file from the string. Something like this perhaps:

```rb
file_from_string "/var/django/.ssh/id_rsa" do
    source ssh_key
    owner "django"
    group "django"
    mode 00600
end
```

Answer (score 50):

Use the [`file`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html) resource and specify the file contents to the `content` property.

In your case, this would result in a resource definition similar to this:

```rb
file "/var/django/.ssh/id_rsa" do
  content ssh_key
  owner "django"
  group "django"
  mode 00600
end
```

Comment: OMG, I looked at the file resource but I missed this.  Thanks!