# How to put every array element in double quotes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

Within Chef, the attribute looks as below:

```
default['cluster']['ipaddress'] = ["10.211.130.108", "10.211.242.203"]
```

Within Chef recipe, I have put every array element in double quotes, using `map`:

```
json_nodes = node['consul']['cluster']['ipaddress'].map { |s| "#{s.to_s}:8300" }

bash 'configuring file.json' do
  code <<-EOH
    echo #{json_nodes} > "/home/user1/file.json"
  EOH
end
```

I get the following output within the file `/home/user1/file.json`:

```
[10.211.130.108:8300, 10.211.242.203:8300]
```

The output should have double quotes as follows:

```
["10.211.130.108:8300", "10.211.242.203:8300"]
```

Comment: The output is really as you described, not `"10.211.130.108:8300,10.211.242.203:8300"`?

Comment: How are you "outputting" this in Chef?

Comment: I have edited my question. please help me out. thanks @StephenKing

Comment: Have a look at the [file](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html) resource. Also [this question here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292579/generate-a-file-from-a-string-without-having-to-create-a-template-file-in-chef).

Comment: That you want to put that into a file via chef's bash resource is kind of the most important information!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
json_nodes = node['cluster']['ipaddress'].map { |s| "#{s.to_s}:8300" }
```

I don't have your data but here is an example from my console:

```
[3] pry(main)> arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4] pry(main)> arr.map { |s| "#{s.to_s}:3000" }
=> ["1:3000", "2:3000", "3:3000", "4:3000", "5:3000"]
```

Note that when I put the .join on the end, it concats them all in a single string.

```
[8] pry(main)> arr.map { |s| "#{s.to_s}:3000" }.join(',')
=> "1:3000,2:3000,3:3000,4:3000,5:3000"
```

Comment: I don't see the double quotes. The output is still `[10.211.130.108:8300,10.211.242.203:8300]`

Comment: Are you still doing the .join(',') on the end? If so, that's going to concat all the elements into a comma delmited string. If you want the elements of the array to be double quoted, my answer should work.

Comment: It is not working. can you help with the answer that I have posted recently

Comment: I am getting this output without putting .join(',')   `[10.211.130.108:8300, 10.211.242.203:8300]`

Comment: I added some example code straight from my console. Hope it helps.

Comment: in my case, `arr = [ "1", "2"]. ` will that make some difference?

Answer (score 1):

Things become a lot easier, when you use Chef in the way it is made for (and don't call bash..). Your problem translated to solving it in Chef is:

```
file "/home/user1/file.json" do
  content node['consul']['cluster']['ipaddress'].map { |s| "#{s}:8300" }.to_s
end
```

If you need non-root ownership and read permissions, have a look at the [`owner` and `mode` options of the file resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html).

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you specified in your own answer. It's a bit strange though, the string you are aiming looks like an array declaration.

```
a = ['10.211.130.108','10.211.242.203']
a.map! { |s| "\"#{s}:8300\"" }
result = "[#{a.join(',')}]"
puts result
# Output: ["10.211.130.108:8300","10.211.242.203:8300"]
```

Comment: I don't see the double quotes. The output is still `[10.211.130.108:8300,10.211.242.203:8300]`

Comment: By replacing `map` with `each`, I am still not getting the double quotes. Please check at your end.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. It works now. See edited answer which includes a test. Beware that the map! method will modify your original array in-place. If that is undesired, use the "map" method (without the exclamation mark) and store the returned array in another variable.

Comment: I have created an answer, can you help with that. `I want output to be surrounded with [] also`

Comment: See my updated answer. If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Comment: as soon as I put join, the double quotes go away. please test it properly at your end. I am getting this output `[[10.211.130.108, 10.211.242.203]:8300]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116828/discussion-between-meallhour-and-brunofacca).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get double quotes using the following:

```
json_nodes = node['cluster']['ipaddress'].map { |s| "\"#{s.to_s}:8300\"" }
```

Comment: Sure, but if you still use the `bash` resource for that, you're simply using Chef in a completely wrong way. You just shouldn't do it this way, then you don't run into that quoting problem because you don't have to escape the bash command.